# What is the best way to get the result through Java8 function?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to filter elements and then sort based on certain column. Post that I would need to find the unique entries based on combination of columns. Since it is file processing, pipe(|) is used as delimiter to denote the column value.

```
String s1= "12|Thor|Asgaurd|1000000|Avenger|Active"
String s2= "234|Iron man|New York|9999999|Avenger|Active"
String s3= "420|Loki|Asgaurd|||Inactive"
String s4= "12|Thor|Asgaurd Bank|1000000|Avenger HQ|Active"
```

Data first needs to be filtered based on the Active/Inactive status. Then it needs to be sorted based on 4th column. Lastly, the uniqueness needs to be maintained by combining column 1,2,3.

Expected Output =

```
"234|Iron man|New York|9999999|Avenger|Active"
"12|Thor|Asgaurd|1000000|Avenger|Active"
```

Comment: You need a better abstraction than a String.

Comment: I'd create a pojo to represent an Avenger implementing `Comparable`, and splitting the input string by "|" in its constructor. You can then define equality/hashCode based on your requirements, which will allow you to identify unique values. You will have to implement `compareTo`, which will allow you to define the default sort order based again on your requirements. You will have fields representing each of the pipe-separated tokens, whose getters will come in handy when filtering and sorting.

Comment: _"the uniqueness needs to be maintained by combining column 1,2,3."_ So should the result not just have the entries from `s1`, `s2` and `s4` not just `s3` and `s1`? Or how do you get rid of `s4` with "Asgaurd Bank" in column 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should create an Object which represents your String data. Something like this:

```
public class MyObject {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private Integer value;
    private String category;
    private String state;

    public MyObject(String entry) {
        String[] parts = entry.split("\\|");
        if (parts.length != 6) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("entry has not 6 parts");
        }
        id = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        name = parts[1];
        location = parts[2];
        try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
        }
        category = parts[4];
        state = parts[5];
    }

    // getters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.join("|", String.valueOf(id), name, location, String.valueOf(value), category, state);
    }
}
```

With this you can create a Stream of objects from your Strings and to the filter, sort and distinct operations afterwards:

```
Collection<MyObject> result = Stream.of(s1, s2, s3, s4)
        .map(MyObject::new)
        .filter(o -> "Active".equals(o.getState()))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getValue).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> Arrays.asList(o.getId(), o.getName()), 
                Function.identity(), (o1, o2) -> o1, LinkedHashMap::new))
        .values();

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

After the map operation you filter the values by state and sort them by column 4 (`value` in my case). At the end you collect all the values in a map for the distinct operation. Add all values you need distinction for to the `Arrays.asList()`. As values the map takes all the original values (`Function.identity()`). For duplicates we keep the first value (`(o1, o2) -> o1`) and we are using a `LinkedHashMap` to keep the order of the items. At the end wee use only the values of the map.

If you need a `List` instead of a `Collection` use `new ArrayList(result)`.

The result will be this:

```
234|Iron man|New York|9999999|Avenger|Active
12|Thor|Asgaurd|1000000|Avenger|Active
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a model class and parsing the string is the way to go, but if for some reaseon you don't want to do that you can do it this way:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

List<String> result = Stream.of(s1, s2, s3, s4)
            .filter(s -> s.split("\\|")[5].equals("Active"))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.split("\\|")[4]))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: First of all `s.split("|")` will not work, because `split()` has a regex as parameter so you should use `"\\|"`. Calling `split()` twice in filter and sort step is also not good for performance. It would be better to split the lines once and join them at the end.

Comment: I admin that I overlooked the arguments passed to the split method and updated my answer accordingly. Regarding the performance issue however, this was just a suggestion of a potential implementation with the java Stream API, and as such is not written in stone and can be adapted based on the requirements at hand. In the implementation above I sacrificed performance for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're unable to filter while everything is string only.
Try this,

> create a new model class which can hold your columns.
>   Ex:

```
class MyData{
 private String name;
 private String city;
 private String distance;
 private String organization;
 private String status;
 //And create Getter Setter method for all above fields.
}
```

> Now came to your main class where you can play with your code stuff.

```
Map<MyData> map = new HashMap<MyData>();
 MyData myData = new MyData();
 myData.setName("Thor");
 myData.setCity("Asgaurd");
 myData.setDistance("1000000");
 myData.setOrganization("Avenger");
 myData.setStatus("Active");
 map.put(12, myData);
//Same thing for all other data (note: use the loop for data insertion in map)

Map<String, MyData> sorted = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(comparingByValue()).collect(toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue().getName(), (e1, e2) -> e2,LinkedHashMap::new));

System.out.println("map after sorting by values: " + sorted);
```

Comment: `Map<MyData> map = new HashMap<MyData>();` does not work. A map needs a key and a value.

Comment: Yes, Samuel Philipp,

> Here As key I've wrote the map.put(12, myData) where 12 is the key which derives from.

String s1= "12|Thor|Asgaurd|1000000|Avenger|Active"

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your task this way:

Firstly, just create POJO(Plain Old Java Object) and override the `toString()` method.

```
class MarvelPerson {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String origin;
    private Integer point = null;
    private String faction;
    private String status;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    public void setOrigin(String origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    public Integer getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public void setPoint(Integer point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

    public String getFaction() {
        return faction;
    }

    public void setFaction(String faction) {
        this.faction = faction;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(id);
        builder.append("|");
        builder.append(name);
        builder.append("|");
        builder.append(origin);
        builder.append("|");
        if(point != null) {
            builder.append(point);
        }
        builder.append("|");
        if(faction != null) {
            builder.append(faction);
        }
        builder.append("|");
        builder.append(status);

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Then, you should write the parser from string to `MarvelPerson`. *Side note: Carefully, my implementation is pretty basic, and I suppose it should be modified because I may not have foreseen some corner cases.*

```
class PersonParser {

    static MarvelPerson parse(String data) {
        MarvelPerson person = new MarvelPerson();

        String[] array = data.split("\\|", -1);

        person.setId(Integer.parseInt(array[0]));
        person.setName(array[1]);
        person.setOrigin(array[2]);

        if(!array[3].isEmpty()) {
            person.setPoint(Integer.parseInt(array[3]));
        }

        if(!array[4].isEmpty()) {
            person.setFaction(array[4]);
        }

        person.setStatus(array[5]);

        return person;
    }

}
```

And then your solution:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MarvelPerson> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(PersonParser.parse("12|Thor|Asgaurd|1000000|Avenger|Active"));
        list.add(PersonParser.parse("234|Iron man|New York|9999999|Avenger|Active"));
        list.add(PersonParser.parse("420|Loki|Asgaurd|||Inactive"));
        list.add(PersonParser.parse("12|Thor|Asgaurd Bank|1000000|Avenger HQ|Actie"));

        list.stream()
                .filter(marvelPerson -> marvelPerson.getStatus().equals("Active"))
                .sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.getPoint() <= o2.getPoint() ? 1 : -1)
                .forEach(marvelPerson -> {
                    System.out.println(marvelPerson.toString());
                });
    }

}
```

The output to be printed:

> 234|Iron man|New York|9999999|Avenger|Active
>   12|Thor|Asgaurd|1000000|Avenger|Active

Comment: You also can use `Comparator.comparing(MarvelPerson::getPoints).reversed()` for the `sorted()` part to make it more readable.

Comment: The `forEach` method can be rewritten to this: `forEach(System.out::println)`. `toString()` is redundant.